# Custom object has standard "List" action , how to get a "List" button onto the page layout?

Tags: custom-object, page-layout, button, list-button

I must be missing something simple.

I have made a custom object, call it TestLog. If I click  my TestLog object to see details, in the section "Buttons, Links, and Actions" I see eight items: Accept, Clone, Delete, Edit, List, New, TestLogs Tab, and View. Great!

The section "Page Layouts" has one item, "TestLog Layout". I click "Edit" and the enhanced page layout editor comes up. The section "Testlog Detail" has three standard buttons (Edit, Delete, Clone) and no custom buttons.

When I click "Buttons" in the upper pane, it lists those three (greyed-out) and also "Submit for Approval".

How can I make the "List" and "Testlogs Tab" action buttons part of the layout? Must I replace this standard layout with a VisualForce page?

Comment: Go to `Setup > Customize > Tabs`. Have you added a custom tab for your TestLog object? It sounds like you just want a tab so you can access your object through the UI and view lists and filters. If so, start with the custom tab.

Comment: `Setup > Create > Tabs`

Comment: I am trying to add buttons to the page layout.  That is not the home tab layout, but rather the default page layout, which displays a record of my custom object in the UI. Basically the problem is , I do not know how to convince the enhanced page layout editor to add the buttons to that layout.  (One of the buttons I want would perform the action "Testlogs Tab", switching from the view of a record to the home page.  Another would perform the action "List".)  These buttons already seem to exist, but the editor seems not to know.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this, but that is not what I am trying to do. I am trying to add buttons to the layout with which the UI displays one record of my custom object. I see the buttons in the design of the object. I do not know how to get the enhanced page layout editor to emplace the buttons on that layout. (if that is possible!) I am not trying to create or customize tabs.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure, now that I have more experience, that my custom buttons just cannot be placed on a detail page layout because of what they do. So, the editor refused to let me place them onto the page layout. This sort of makes sense, because they would have to be usable while editing a record as well as just viewing it. For the standard buttons, the system knows not to display (for example) "Clone" while editing, but it will not accept custom buttons which are inappropriate while editing.